# Filling 2D dynamicaly allocated array in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix, 2d

does anyone know how to fill two-dimensional (dynamic) array in C?
I have this:

```
double** A;
A = ( double** )malloc( 2*sizeof( double* ));
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) A[i] = ( double* )malloc( 3 );
A[0][0] = 1;
A[0][1] = 2;
A[0][2] = 3;
A[1][0] = 4;
A[1][1] = 5;
A[1][2] = 6;       
printf("%d", A[1][1]);
```

but it prints me only zero... :/

Does anyone help? THX :)

Comment: `( double* )malloc( 3 );` needs a `sizeof` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) A[i] = ( double* )malloc( 3 );
```

allocates three *bytes* to `A[i]`. You need

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) A[i] = ( double* )malloc( 3 * sizeof(double) );
```

Since you allocate not enough space, the filling of the array writes outside the allocated memory and that invokes undefined behaviour.

And

```
printf("%d", A[1][1]);
```

tries to print a `double` with a conversion format for an `int`, which also invokes undefined behaviour. You need to print `double`s with a `%f` (or `%g`, `%e`, or some others) conversion,

```
printf("%f", A[1][1]);
```

is what you (probably) want.

Two common things to happen in that case are

- the `double` is passed in a floating point register, but `printf` reads a general purpose register (common on x86_64)
- `printf` reads part of the bytes making up the `double` and interprets them as an `int` (common on 32-bit x86), since the `double` values you store are integral, the significands have many zero bits, and then on little-endian systems, the bits that `printf` reads are all zero.

Comment: In addition to this, would you throw in the UB of `printf("%d", A[1][1]);`?

Comment: @kelly Yup, the wrong conversion for `printf` added that to the answer.